# I need suggestions on a Good example for a slide show/gallery for website

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, slideshow

I have never written a slide show before and having trouble getting it started. I search the net for some good tutorials but I could not find one that i could use. My gallery will also have comments on it so I need it to be ajax driven. NOt sure if this is good info but I have all the pictures stored inside of an array so, it would be easier if I could find something that uses that as well. Thanks for any help.

I am using asp.net c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using jQuery. They have many slider implementations that work out of the box using jQuery. Integrating them into your site is quick and painless.

Here is a resource that lists a few of them. The degree to which you can customize them varies, along with the look and feel, and features. http://designmodo.com/jquery-slider-scripts-tutorials/